# Why does creating a Swift array the right size to begin with slow things down?

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, vector, microbenchmark

Update: I made a mistake in this measurement, by using debug mode. In release mode, I get the expected result.

---

I need to append a large number of integers to a Swift array:

```
let numBytes = 12 * 1048576 * 3

let start = Date()
var appendingImage = [UInt8]()
for i in 0..<numBytes {
  appendingImage.append(UInt8(i % 256))
}

print("Append took \(-start.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
```

This takes 0.5 seconds (on an iPhone 7 Plus).

I thought it will be faster to initialise it to the right size to begin with, but that takes 1s:

```
var precreatedImage = Array(repeating: UInt8(0), count: numBytes)
for i in 0..<numBytes {
  precreatedImage[i] = UInt8(i % 256)
}
print("Precreated took \(-start.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
```

Why is this happening? I thought the latter code fragment doesn't need to keep reallocating the array and copying all the elements whenever it overflows, so it should be faster.

I suspected initialising an array with 36M zeros is slow, but it takes only 0.03 seconds. That can't account for the difference of 0.5s.

I ran this test thrice, and the first code fragment always takes 0.4-0.5 seconds, while the second one always takes 1 - 1.2 seconds.

Comment: What level if optimization you are using?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on a Mac (in Release mode). I measure Append 0.137sec vs Precreated 0.05 sec.

Comment: You're right — it was an artifact caused by debug mode. It works as expected in release mode.

Comment: Up voted both comments. Now, the question is do you post an answer to your own question - I expected this would be correct (because it allocates enough memory?) - with a good explanation or should you remove/delete the question.

Comment: @dfd I edited the question to say so right at the beginning. Take a look.

Comment: Answer and accept your own solution. That preserves the up votes, and could be helpful to someone new at using debug/release mode.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. I wasn't being "snarky" with my comment, I really meant to ask if this question *deserves* some sort of answer for all of us "future" coders. Still relatively new to SO, so I would have thought a self-answered question would be *most* helpful to all.

Comment: @dfd I didn't interpret it negatively, so no worries :)